# detect when Touch Keyboard opens in WPF

Tags: wpf, windows-10

I'm working on a WPF application, mostly targeted at windows 10 but it could also be run on older versions.  By default, if I open the app while in tablet mode, the keyboard will open when I focus a textbox, and close when the textbox loses focus, but if I manually close the keyboard it won't open anymore (very annoying as this is a natural thing to do).  I can live with that, but the problem is that the keyboard opens over my application, so the user can't see 50% of it, including most of the text boxes, which makes it hard for them to select something else to 'defocus' and close the keyboard.

If I could get some notification when they touch keyboard opens, it'd be fairly easy to have some UI code to make sure the proper things are displayed, but I can't find any way to get an event when the keyboard opens.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/WPF-Samples/tree/master/Input%20and%20Commands/TouchKeyboard/TouchKeyboardNotifier) on Windows 10 Anniversary Edition and above to get notifications from the touch keyboard.

Comment: @zacaj did you get this to work? I have a similar requirement and would like to know if this is the way to go. I want to add a margin at the bottom of my screen when the keyboard is opened, so all fields are accessible.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me.  The linked sample on github allows you to add listener events to the Touch Keyboard.